# How to create a while loop that continuously detects if scraped data in a list changes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

pages = ["movies", "series"]
printed = []
for page in pages:
    req = Request("https://www.thenetnaija.com/videos/" + page, headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})

    webpage = urlopen(req, timeout=10)

    b4 = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

    movie_list = b4.find_all("div", {"class" : "video-files"})


    for allContainers in movie_list:
        filmName = allContainers.find('img').get('alt')
        printed.append(filmName)
        print(printed)
for get in printed:
requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot:AAEapVykIXdphGYaH5ZjXuhpFaFw7wpi5Bs/sendMessage?chat_id=&text={}".format(get))
```

I want to use a while loop to let the program run infinitely and only send the requests to my telegram chat if the data in the list has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example as a basis how to check the movies/series periodically (The example is using `set.difference` to determine if there are changes):

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


def get_movies(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "XYZ/3.0"}
    req = Request(url, headers=headers)
    b4 = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req, timeout=10), "html.parser")
    return set(a.get_text(strip=True) for a in b4.select("h2 a"))


url = "https://www.thenetnaija.com/videos/{}"
pages = {
    "movies": get_movies(url.format("movies")),
    "series": get_movies(url.format("series")),
}

while True:
    time.sleep(10)  # <-- sleep 10sec before checking again

    for k, v in pages.items():
        new_movies = get_movies(url.format(k))
        difference = new_movies.difference(v)

        if difference:
            print("New {}:".format(k))
            print(difference)
            pages[k] = new_movies

            # do stuff here (post to telegram etc.)
            # ...
        else:
            print("No new {}".format(k))
```